# SQLAlchemy (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'dict'

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Couldn't find a solution on the web for my problem.
I am trying to insert this pandas df to a Postgresql table using SQLAlchemy

- Pandas 0.24.2
- sqlalchemy 1.3.3
- python 3.7

Relevant part of my code is below:

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:pass@host:5432/db')

file = open('GameRoundMessageBlackjackSample.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
json_dict = json.load(file)
df = json_normalize(json_dict, record_path='cards', meta=['bet', 'dealerId', 'dealerName', 'gameOutcome', 'gameRoundDuration', 'gameRoundId', 'gameType', 'tableId', 'win'])
df = df[['win', 'betAmount', 'bets']]

df.to_sql('test_netent_data', engine, if_exists='append')
```

[image]

When I try to load this table to sql without the column 'bets' everyting works as expected. But when I include it i get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt 
type 'dict'
[SQL: INSERT INTO test_netent_data (index, win, "betAmount", bets) VALUES (%(index)s, %(win)s, %(betAmount)s, %(bets)s)]
[parameters: ({'index': 0, 'win': '2000.00', 'betAmount': '1212112', 'bets': [{'name': '1', 'amount': '1212112'}]}, {'index': 1, 'win': '2000.00', 'betAmount': '1212000', 'bets': [{'name': '1', 'amount': '1212000'}]}, {'index': 2, 'win': '2000.00', 'betAmount': '1212112', 'bets': [{'name': '1', 'amount': '1212112'}]}, {'index': 3, 'win': '2000.00', 'betAmount': '1212000', 'bets': [{'name': '1', 'amount': '1212000'}]}, {'index': 4, 'win': '2000.00', 'betAmount': '1212112', 'bets': [{'name': '1', 'amount': '1212112'}]}, {'index': 5, 'win': '2000.00', 'betAmount': '1212000', 'bets': [{'name': '1', 'amount': '1212000'}]}, {'index': 6, 'win': '2000.00', 'betAmount': '1212112', 'bets': [{'name': '1', 'amount': '1212112'}]}, {'index': 7, 'win': '2000.00', 'betAmount': '1212000', 'bets': [{'name': '1', 'amount': '1212000'}]})]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

I have checked the type of this column but it is (type object) no different from other columns. Ive also tried to convert it to string and got a bunch of other errors.
I believe there should be a simple solution which I can't get my head around.

Comment: What is the type of the bets column in postgres?

Comment: Thanks for reply.
print(df.dtypes) shows: win -> object, betAmount -> object, bets -> object.
I could've flattened json fully but I want to avoid it and keep some data to look like as a json string or python dict

Comment: No, not in python, in postgres.  What is the definition of the test_netent_data table?

Comment: All of the columns are 'text'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For me, the better way will be parse this list dict into separated columns. However if you want add column *bets* into SQL table you need to convert it. You wrote that this is object, but it is list with dicts. Below is code how to convert it into string:

```
df['bets'] = list(map(lambda x: json.dumps(x), df['bets']))
```

Answer (score 19):

Just use dataframe apply

```
df['bets'] = df['bets'].apply(json.dumps)
```

Answer (score 16):

Since you're using `pandas.DataFrame.to_sql`, a better alternative is to leverage the native `JSON` type:

```
df.to_sql(
  'test_netent_data',
  engine,
  if_exists='append',
  dtype={"bets": sqlalchemy.types.JSON},
)
```

(inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/41469431/554319)

Comment: this should be the top answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just register an adapter for type **dict** with **psycopg2**:

```
from psycopg2.extensions import register_adapter, AsIs
import json

def adapt_dict(dict_var):
    return AsIs("'" + json.dumps(dict_var) + "'")

register_adapter(dict, adapt_dict)
```