# pandas to_sql can't adapt type 'dict'

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, pandas-to-sql

I have to write a pandas dataframe to a PostgreSQL table. Here you find a snippet of code:

```
values = [1, 1]
d = {'col1': values, 'col2': values}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.to_sql('prograd_dashboard', con=dbConnection, if_exists='replace', index=False,  method='multi')
```

I run into this error message:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'dict' 'INSERT INTO prograd_dashboard (col1, col2) VALUES (%(col1)s, %(col2)s)' {'col1': {'col1': 1, 'col2': 1}, 'col2': {'col1': 1, 'col2': 1}}
```

As you can see, there is no dict in the dataframe. However, there is in fact a dict in the sqlalchemy-generated insert command.

If I set method=None, the code works perfectly. However, performance degrades as the number of records increases.

How can I solve this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLAlchemy (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'dict'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56808425/sqlalchemy-psycopg2-programmingerror-cant-adapt-type-dict)

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem by updating pandas and SQLAlchemy libraries.

Comment: What version of pandas as SQL Alchemy were you using for the fix?

Comment: I am currently using  version 1.3.24