# pandas to_sql with dict raises "can't adapt type 'dict'", is there a way to avoid `dumps`?

Tags: sql, json, pandas, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to load a simple pandas DataFrame on a PostgreSQL table (pandas 1.4, Postgres 13):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{"index": 1, "properties": {"a": 1, "b": 2}}])
df.to_sql("_test_table", con, if_exists="replace")
```

However, I get `ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'dict'`.

I have seen in [other Stack Overflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64965014/554319) that applying `json.dumps` fixes the issue, and they are right. However, I would like to know if there's a way to leverage PostgreSQL [`JSON`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) types instead of converting the information to a string.

The `psycopg2` documentation mentions ["JSON Adaptation"](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#json-adaptation), but running `psycopg2.extensions.register_adapter(dict, psycopg2.extras.Json)` at the beginning ends up, again, storing the data as `text`.

There are a couple of mentions of JSON on [the psycopg2 FAQ](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/faq.html#faq-json-adapt), but I don't think they answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is essentially a duplicate of [Writing JSON column to Postgres using Pandas .to_sql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41469430/554319): the solution is to use the `dtype` parameter of `.to_sql` with `sqlalchemy.types.JSON`:

```
import sqlalchemy


df = pd.DataFrame([{"index": 1, "properties": {"a": 1, "b": 2}}])
df.to_sql("_test_table", dwh_con, if_exists="replace", dtype={"properties": sqlalchemy.types.JSON})
```

And now everything works.