# Use pandas.DataFrame.to_sql to update a JSON column in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have a MySQL table with a JSON column.
I am able to write into this JSON field following [either answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41469430/writing-json-column-to-postgres-using-pandas-to-sql), 
but I have not yet found a solution to be able to update the json field with the same method.

The solution I tried:

```py
out_df.to_sql('my_table', my_sql_alchemy_engine, if_exists='append')
```

can go 2 ways:

- if there are no unique keys in my table, the rows are simply added at the end of the table, with the JSON field containing only the values I wanted to make an update with
- If there are unique fields, i get an `IntegrityError`

Is there any way to make that work, or should I find another solution to update my JSON fields ?