# dataframe to_sql JSON datatype without double quotes

Tags: mysql, pandas, dataframe, mysql-workbench, python-3.7

I'm trying to upload a list of lists as JSON using df.to_sql but it always upload with double quotes around it.

Desired output:

| A header | Geometry |
| --- | --- |
| First | [[12.3, 45.6], [7.8, 9.1]] |
| Second | [[12.3, 45.6], [7.8, 9.2]] |

Current output:

| A header | Geometry |
| --- | --- |
| First | "[[12.3, 45.6], [7.8, 9.1]]" |
| Second | "[[12.3, 45.6], [7.8, 9.2]]" |

Uploading snippet:

```
def upload_df(connection, df, table_name):
    dtype = { 
        'Geometry':JSON
    }
    schema = "schema"
    df.to_sql(table_name, connection,schema=schema,if_exists='replace',index=False, chunksize=1000, dtype=dtype)
```

Not sure if this is enough info to get help on this.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the `Geometry` column in the dataframe is a list, not a string?

Comment: Because your `dtype` value is supposed to be the way to do it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41469431/1491895