# How to write JSON column to MySQL using pandas.to_sql?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I struggled quite a while trying to save into MySQL a table containing JSON columns, using SQLAlchemy and pandas' to_sql.

I got this error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) Failed processing pyformat-parameters; Python 'list' cannot be converted to a MySQL type
```

when trying to do it the standard way below. I have a pandas dataframe (df) where I have two columns containing JSONs ('videos', and 'newsitems').

```
import sqlalchemy
connection = sqlalchemy.create_engine(f"mysql+mysqlconnector://{user}:{pw}@{host}/{db}")
table_name = 'TABLENAME'
df.to_sql(table_name, 
          connection, 
          if_exists='append', 
          index=False)
```

Comment: I'm getting an error with my json column "scans":
ValueError: scans (<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.JSON'>) not a string

Answer (score 0):

Now I found a response elsewhere, about postgresql - which works as finely with MySQL. Adding the last two lines `dtype={...}` fixed the issue

```
import sqlalchemy
connection = sqlalchemy.create_engine(f"mysql+mysqlconnector://{user}:{pw}@{host}/{db}")
table_name = 'TABLENAME'
df.to_sql(table_name, 
          connection, 
          if_exists='append', 
          index=False,
          dtype={'videos': sqlalchemy.types.JSON,
                 'newsitems': sqlalchemy.types.JSON})
```

The original Q&A that helped me solve the issue was this

[Writing JSON column to Postgres using Pandas .to_sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41469430/writing-json-column-to-postgres-using-pandas-to-sql)